sender and receiver udp using gstreamer
I try to send a gstreamer code line as sender with udp connection protocol then I want to received another gstreamer code line as a receiver. Here are the sender and receiver codes and their each error respecively.
SENDER:
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.144.25:8554/main.264 short-header=TRUE latency=400 connection-speed=3000 timeout=50000000 ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! rtph265pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 auto-multicast=true 

RECEIVER:
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc multicast-group port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H265 ! rtph265depay ! avdec_h265 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock

I wanted to get an video from my camera on the vlc using with udpsquared v2.

Looks like your video source comes from an RTSP, are you sure it's comes as an h265 stream? Also, why are you depaying and re-paying?
The pipe works using videotestsrc instead of your source, that's why I'm wondering if the stream comes as h265. (BTW: your pipe was a typo for the multicast-group):
# Receiver
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc multicast-group=224.1.1.1 port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H265" ! rtph265depay ! avdec_h265 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false

# Sender
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! x265enc ! rtph265pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 auto-multicast=true

You could add GST_DEBUG=2 before gst-launch-1.0 to show more information about the errors
